# Go can't find sdl

Tags: go, github, mingw, sdl, sdl-2

I've been trying to install sdl for go for a while now. I used this tutorial on github: https://github.com/vinzBad/go-sdl2-tut/blob/master/00_preparation/windows.md

However, every time I enter

```
go get -v github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
```

into cmd or git bash, after being done with everything else, i get

> In file included from go\src\github.com\veandco\go-sdl2\sdl\audio.go:4:0:
>   ./sdl_wrapper.h:2:23: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
>     #include 
>                          ^
>   compilation terminated.

So apparently it cannot find sdl, even though I got it installed and added the paths to my environment variables.

I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: It appears you don't have the development libraries properly installed from step 2.

Comment: Tried doing that step again, still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty... I solved the problem by installing the 32 bit version of go. That's how simple it was...